# SVR fit takes a very short (< 1 min) time, accuracy is around 0%

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a file with numbers separated by `' '`, some of them integers, some floats. When I check that pandas loads the data correctly, everything seems okay. However, when I call the `fit` method (I'm using `rbf`) the "learning" happens very fast, which indicates something is wrong.

Things I've tried:

- convert all numbers to floats (I know it won't accept strings and numbers, but do all features have to be the same type?)
- used column names (right now I don't have column names, but that shouldn't matter)

I've trained similar models in Java and I know fitting is supposed to take a long time - this is my first attempt at python. I added the code I wrote below:

```
features = pd.read_csv('features.csv', header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
print(features.shape) # this prints (13240, 12)
labels = pd.read_csv('labels.csv', header=None, delim_whitespace=True).values.ravel()
print(labels.shape) # this prints (13240,)
features_train, features_test = train_test_split(features, test_size=0.1)
reads_train, reads_test = train_test_split(labels, test_size=0.1)

svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma='auto')
svr_rbf.fit(features_train, reads_train)

predicted = svr_rbf.predict(features_test)
print(r2_score(reads_test, predicted)) # prints -0.08997598845415777
```

This is features.head(5):

```
      0      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11


0   2.70   4.17  4.17   740  2577  2209  2209   454   454   546   546   315


1   2.87   3.22  1.04  3797  2880  3393     0  2357  2357  2357  2547   363


2   3.04   3.30  1.57  3101  2887  3282  1460   488   488  3962  3962   228


3  11.22  12.52  9.04  1113  3187   157  1872  1301  1301  1301  1301  1782


4  17.56  17.56  9.91   226  1349   391  3012   468   468   468   357   309
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is, the problem is where you split training and test data twice, for labels and features separately. `train_test_split` both times selects randomly the 10% test data rows, so probably there are different indices in the test set of the labels than the test set of the features.

You have to do the training and test data split for features and labels simultaneously to make sure that the labels and features still match afterwards:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)
```

Comment: Hmmm... I thought train_test_split doesn't pick randomly unless you specify it. It doesn't seem to make a difference when I'm making the change you suggested though.

Comment: If you don't specify anything in train_test_split, the data is shuffled before splitting.

Comment: Another thing: You were talking about accuracy. For r2 score, however, the best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse). A constant model that always predicts the expected value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a R^2 score of 0.0

Comment: It would also help if you posted snapshots of the data frames.

Comment: I added what the features look like and the accuracy. In any case, a few thousands lines of code and 12 features should take a few hours to fit. Something else is wrong with the setup.

Comment: @RockOnRockOut Have you tried correcting the train_test_split as suggested in the answer? This is definitely an error in your code that should be corrected. Run it again and check the r2 score after that. Also, I don't necessarily think it should take hours. A few thousands observations is definitely not "big data"..

Answer (score 0):

As Julia already mentioned, try to adjust the `train_test_split`into one command:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
features_train, features_test, reads_train, reads_test = train_test_split( features, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

This should give you the same split for features and labels.

If you are still unsatisfied with the `r2` try to use less features and try to tune your SVR funciton. This is the documentation with the parameters:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html